# Node.js: When exactly one should emit a 'drain' event?

Tags: node.js, events, asynchronous, queue, worker

I'm the author of this node.js lib: [async-kit](https://www.npmjs.org/package/async-kit).

I'm currently coding a worker/queue feature.

By default, the worker process one job at a time, but the concurrency level can be adjusted to anything.

Suppose I create a worker with a concurrency level of 3, so up to 3 async job can be pending at any time. At the time of writing, my lib will emit the 'drain' event when no more jobs are pending, i.e. when all jobs have triggered their callback. Let's call that the 'no-more-pending-job' event for instance.

However, one may want an event to be emitted anytime the number of pending jobs drop below 3, meaning that if a new job is added to the queue, it will run immediately. Let's call it temporarily the 'ready-to-process-new-job-right-now' event. In fact, this event is way more useful than the 'no-more-pending-job' event.

So... What is exactly the standard in node.js for the 'drain' event? Is it more like 'no-more-pending-job' or like 'ready-to-process-new-job-right-now'?

I tend toward the first one, also the second one seems way more useful, and I can't find a lib that implement the two types of event, so I can't find either a standardized name for the 'ready-to-process-new-job-right-now'.

Also it is important to notice that for the "one-job-at-a-time" default behavior, those two events would fire at the same time anyway.

Any advice?

Comment: It sounds like you should just implement this queue as a [Writable stream](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_writable_1), have you tried that? That would give you `drain` automatically and the 'ready-to-process-new-job-right-now' would be a matter of checking the return value of `queueStream.write()`.

Comment: Your idea seems to have some potential, I will think about it. You deserve a +1 ;)